# why use - instead off _ in url

Tags: url

why use - instead off _ in url?
Url contain '_' seems like no bad effects.

Comment: because "why-use-instead-off-in-url" looks better than  "why_use_instead_off_in_url" :D

Comment: Just this reason? Whether it also helps to SEO? i am not certain about it. Or because it is Hyphen, then better at connect words than Underscore in syntax.

Comment: Google webmaster central has a bit on this topic. See [here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=76329)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

When you read a_long_sentence_with_many_underscores, because you are reading it by letter or word recognition, your eye tracks along the middle of the line, but when you reach an underscore, your eye is more likely to track down a bit and back up for the next word.

When you read a-long-sentence-with-many-dashes, your eye keeps tracking along the same horizon, and by sight, it is easier for your brain to try and ignore them.

Another good reason is that Google and other search engines rank urls that match to search terms higher when the word separator is a dash.

Comment: Interesting enough, it's opposite to me. When reading a_long_sentence, I keep my eyes on the middle line, so I effectively see spaces instead of underscores, which feels better.

Comment: And because Matt Cutts says so. He's an authoritative source from Google: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3SFVfDIS5k

Comment: I'd like to see the linguistic research that validates the eye-tracking claim, because I find underscores much easier to read than dashes.

Answer (score 57):

Underscores are not allowed in a host name. Thus some_place.com is not a valid URL because the host name is not valid. Underscores are permissible in URLS. Thus some-place.com/which_place/ is perfectly legitimate, other concerns aside.

From RFC 1738:

> host
>
> > ```
> >    [...] Fully qualified domain names take the form as described
> >    in Section 3.5 of RFC 1034 [13] and Section 2.1 of RFC 1123
> >    [5]: a sequence of domain labels separated by ".", each domain
> >    label starting and ending with an alphanumerical character and
> >    possibly also containing "-" characters. The rightmost domain
> >    label will never start with a digit, though, which
> >    syntactically distinguishes all domain names from the IP
> >    addresses.
> > ```

Comment: RFC 1738 was replaced by RFC 2396 in 1998.  RFC 2396 allows underscore as "unreserved character" (RFC 2396 was obsoleted by RFC 3986 in 2005).

Comment: [Bug: `java.net.URI` should be updated for RFC 3986](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8019345), filed 2013-06-27.

Answer (score 6):

One main reason is that most anchor tags have `text-decoration:underline` which effectively hides your underscore.
And, a non-tech savvy user wont automatically assume that there is an underscore :)

Answer (score 5):

By the way... it seems several Java network libraries will not be able to interpret a URL correctly when using underscore:

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://www.google-plus.com/");
System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // prints www.google-plus.com

URI uri = URI.create("http://www.google_plus.com/");
System.out.println(uri.getHost()); // prints null
```

Comment: That's because underscores are not legal in domain names (see the answer above with the RFC 1738 reference) and your example has an underscore in the domain name. It is legal, however, to have an underscore in the URI 'path' that follows the domain name part of a URL.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to type (at least on my german keyboard) and see.