# Spring Boot + JPA, PostgreSQL driver returns null for Heroku Remote DB URL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, heroku

I know this question appeared on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions worked for me. I have a Spring Boot application that is auto-configured. I have this `application.properties` :

```
#HEROKU CREDENTIALS
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgres://my_url/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When application is deployed on Heroku everything works perfectly. When I try to run it on my local machine I can't connect to the database.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@69ec93c2 returned null for URL: my_url
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:329) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.14.jar:na]
```

As you can see in the `application.properties` I added the `ssl` and `sslfactory` but no success.

Comment: I think `jdbc:postgres://` should be `jdbc:postgresql://`, but that doesn't seem to be the main problem.

Comment: @codefinger, It actually worked !!! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL prefix `jdbc:postgres://` should be `jdbc:postgresql://`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be related to an underscore in the hostname. Looks like underscores are allowed in hostnames : See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852692/227986

Comment: No underscores. If there were underscores I suppose it wouldn't work at all : ``jdbc:postgres://ec2-174-129-224-33.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d84d5t07vqtcfj``